# How to lazy load content on JQuery tabs that doesn't pertain to any of the tab content(ie. login section or registration section)

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am lazy loading 3 tabs using Query tabs in an asp.net mvc web app.  I have a Login section(username and password) that I would like to display where the tab content usually shows.  I would like this Login section to only load when the user clicks the link at the top of the page. So, I need it lazy loaded too.  How would I do that, I can't seem to figure it out.   Below is my current tab code.  I appreciate your help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $("#tabContainer").tabs();

        });          

     </script>



<div id="menu" style=" background-color:White; width:950px; height:400px; float:left;">             
            <div id="tabContainer">
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="../../Home/GetHomeTab">Home</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="../../Home/GetProductTab">Products</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="../../Home/GetContactUsTab">Contact Us</a></li>                                               
                </ul>                    
            </div>                       
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, you need to add the `select:` event onto your tabs code. here's a quick example:

```
<div id="menu" style=" background-color:White; width:950px; height:400px; float:left;">             
    <div id="tabContainer">
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#tab0">Home</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#tab1">Products</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#tab2">Contact Us</a></li>                                               
        </ul>                    

        <div id="tab0"></div>    
        <div id="tab1"></div> 
        <div id="tab2"></div>       
    </div>          
</div> 

<script>
$(function() {
    var $tabs = $("#tabContainer").tabs({
        select: function(e, ui) {
            var thistab = ui;
            runMethod(thistab.index);
        }
    });
});

function runMethod(thistab) {
    selectedtab = thistab;
    switch (thistab) {
        case 0:
            getTab0Data();
            break;

        case 1:
            getTab1Data();
            break;

        case 2:
            getTab2Data();
            break;
    }
}

function getTab0Data(){
    alert("you clicked Tab 0");
}

function getTab1Data(){
    alert("you clicked Tab 1");
}

function getTab2Data(){
    alert("you clicked Tab 2");
}
</script>
```

**[EDIT]** - i've updated the example so that it runs. both jquery base lib and jquery UI need to be referenced in the page. I also added a jsfiddle to demo it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jimibt/k7ZN6/

basically, the getTab***n***Data() function(s) run an ajax request that populates the appropriate div (i.e. tab0, tab1, tab2 etc) as per the amended structure above.

for jquery ajax, see:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

hope this helps

Comment: did this help...    at all...    in any small way :-)

Comment: [The example that you posted](http://jsbin.com/ocijut/2/edit) doesn't appear to be working at all. How can I get it to work correctly?

Comment: Hi Anderson, you need to reference both jquery base lib and UI. i've updated my answer, plus done an example for you on jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/jimibt/k7ZN6 let me know how you fare... caio--->